# How can I mirror Shotwell library in the directories?

Tags: gnome, shotwell, photo-management

I noticed that when I import pictures in Shotwell, they all get copied to `~/Pictures` but this copy is not synced with deletions or edits I make to the pictures in the library. Also the folder structure doesn't reflect the 'Events' grouping.

Is there a way to make Shotwell do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can decide for yourself where Shotwell keeps and looks for the pictures in "Shotwell Preferences", under "Library Location". Just change the directory next to "Import photo's to:".

When you import photo's into Shotwell using Shotwell, Shotwell organizes the pictures, using a naming scheme that you can define in the "Shotwell Preferences", under "Importing".

In addition, Shotwell can be set to watch its library directory for changes done outside of Shotwell: "Shotwell Preferences", under "Library Location". Make sure "Watch library directory for new files" is checked to have Shotwell update the database according to the files present there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question concerns the reverse direction of the synced: if I edit my library, files are not edited accordingly.

Comment: Shotwell is not destructive, so the original is not touched. A copy is made. When you delete in Shotwell, the original, if it is not moved, certainly is not deleted until you empty the trash.

Comment: Where does Shotwell store the copy?

Comment: Copy of the modified photo is stored in the same dir as the orgininal.